# How to design a tree data structure that supports deletion of elements lower than a given value?

Tags: algorithm, tree

For the purpose of one of my algorithms, I want to create a data structure that supports the following operations in `O(lg n)` time complexity:

- *adding* a new item;
- *searching* for a new item;
- *deleting* all items whose key is lower than a given value.

I guess a tree would be the most suitable data structure to support these operations. However, I actually  don't know how to implement the last one in logarithmic time. How can I design it?

Comment: Does the last bullet point mean deleting *all* items whose key is lower than a given value?

Comment: @delnan: Yes, it does.

Comment: What complexity are you talking about ? In `log(n)` comparisons is easy, but `log(n)` generally is hard (when including the cost of free-ing the memory of each released node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a balanced binary search tree (AVL, red-black, you choose).  Elements lower than a given one will be found in the left children along the path connecting it to the root.  The rest is easy...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which was useful. However, I'm interested in worst case complexity. As far as I know, a typical binary search tree implementation supports these operations in `O(n)` in the worst case.

Comment: Sorry, I meant of course a balanced binary search tree, which does that in O(log n).  I'm updating the answer.